# Che cosa significa "sembrava non aver terra lo reggesse"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Ricominciavo a credere seriamente che la casa racchiudesse
>   almeno un secondo abitatore... un'abitatrice. In ogni caso era evidente che questa persona mi evitava con ogni sua possa; ella aveva, di più, su me un enorme vantaggio, per tacere di altri: il vantaggio della perfetta conoscenza dei luoghi. Ora, uno dei mezzi
>   che mi si offrivano per raggiungerla, se esisteva, pericoloso fra
>   tutti ma forse il più sicuro, poteva essere quello di seguire furtivamente nei suoi numerosissimi andirivieni il vecchio, che in generale **sembrava non aver terra lo reggesse**. Avevo ad esempio notato come, durante la cena e subito dopo, sempre in ogni modo alla medesima ora, egli usasse levarsi di tavola e sparire nelle profondità della casa; spesso riportava, è vero, da tali assenze un piatto o
>   un oggetto qualsiasi, pure non tardai a giudicare che egli volesse
>   con ciò crearsi un alibi, tanto più che talvolta dette assenze duravano molto a lungo.

La mia domanda è sull'espressione "sembrava non aver terra lo reggesse" che appare in questo brano. Si tratta di un modo di dire? Ho cercato alla voce "terra" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione.

Comment: che sia un refuso? "_sembrava non aver terra che lo reggesse_" ? Ovvero era talmente silenzioso da sembrare un fantasma.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Perché dovrebbe essere un refuso?

Comment: come anacoluto, mi suona strano all'orecchio; per questo penso che manchi la congiunzione "che". 
Ora che le me fai notare, rileggendo la frase, è anche possibile sia stata omessa di proposito per non ripeterla visto che è già presente appena prima.
"[...] il vecchio, *che* in generale sembrava non aver terra *che* lo reggesse [...]".

Comment: L’omissione della congiunzione “che” non è strana. Qui la questione riguarda i modi di dire. Sul momento, non mi sembra che lo sia, ma sto provando a cercare.

Comment: Per quanto riguarda il modo di dire in sé, sono abbastanza convinto che sia appunto equivalente a dire che il personaggio si muoveva come un fantasma, in modo talmente silenzioso da sembrare fluttuare senza appoggiarsi per terra.

Comment: Penso anch'io che l'espressione abbia quel significato; penso anche che non sia un "modo di dire" bensì un'invenzione letteraria di Landolfi.

Comment: @Benedetta è decisamente molto plausibile :)

Comment: Si potrebbe azzardare anche un'altra interpretazione: "non stava mai fermo allo stesso posto" ma solo chi ha letto l'intera opera può dire se sia giusto. ;)

Comment: @genespos: Può darsi che sia questo.

Comment: Assodato che manca un *che*, direi che @genespos ha colto nel segno: nessun posto sembrava offrirgli un sostegno adeguato.

Comment: A proposito dell’ellissi di “che”, ho trovato interessante il punto 3 di questa trattazione dell’Enciclopedia dantesca (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/che_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/). L’ellissi è un fenomeno tipico nei primi autori toscani e, da lì, è rimasta, utilizzata da altri autori.

Comment: Devo correggere il mio primo commento: “che” non è congiunzione, ma pronome relativo con funzione di soggetto.

Answer (score 1):

Questa espressione - probabilmente un'invenzione letteraria di Landolfi - significa secondo me che il personaggio si muoveva come un fantasma, in modo talmente silenzioso da sembrare fluttuare senza appoggiarsi per terra.

La frase andrebbe quindi interpretata in questo modo:

> il vecchio, che in generale sembrava non aver terra ***che*** lo reggesse [...]

L'omissione del secondo "che" (pronome relativo facente funzione di soggetto) la rende un po' più difficile da comprendere. Non saprei dire se questa mancanza sia dovuta ad un refuso oppure l'autore abbia commesso questa omissione volontariamente per evitare una ripetizione.

Comment: Come ho scritto anche sotto la domanda, “che” in questo caso non è congiunzione ma pronome relativo con funzione di soggetto.

Comment: @Benedetta risposta modificata.

Comment: Non penso che l'assenza di questo "che" possa trattarsi di un refuso. Io ho il libro edito da Adelphi, ma poi ho trovato [questo](https://is.muni.cz/el/1421/podzim2009/IJ0B617b/Landolfi_-_Racconto_d_autunno.pdf) che immagino corrisponda a [questo libro](http://www.fantascienza.com/catalogo/volumi/NILF105820/opere-i-1937-1959/). E poi Landolfi aveva un grande dominio della lingua.

Comment: Sono d’accordo con @Charo: si tratta di un’ellissi, non di un refuso.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: grazie!